# replace number+string with string+number (using regex)

Tags: regex, string, search, replace, numbers

I am using search and replace in an advanced text editor that supports regex.

Now i want to replace 
**##,##-**
with 
**-##,##** (where ##,## stands for any number)

Any help what search and replace expressions I need to use to achieve this?

E.g. **\d-** will only replace the **-** itself.

Comment: Care to say which 'advanced text editor'?

Comment: Can you post some examples of lines before and after the replacement? ("Any number" is pretty vague. I assume you *do* want `1-` changed to `-1` and do *not* want `one-` changed to `-one`, but there are a lot of cases where I don't know whether you would want them changed.)

Comment: @ruakh sorry didnt mention I am searching a collumn, so I am only dealing with digits. ( I meant to say any number of digits) bad english - no native speaker ;) in any case cristobalitos solution did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the replace semantics are on your advanced text editor but you'll likely want to use grouping to do the replacement. Something like

```
(\d+)(,?)(\d+)-
```

will match the pattern and assuming something like $1 matches the groups (the bits between the brackets), then

```
-$1$2$3
```

should suffice where `$2` matches the (I'm guessing optional) ','.

Comment: Although your regex marks the `,` as optional, it requires at least one digit before it *and* at least one digit after it, with the effect that it requires at least two digits even if there is no comma. I doubt that is intentional. Also -- there's no need to have three separate capture groups. Replacing `(\d+,?\d+)-` with `-$1` would have the same effect.